# Adding or moving an element in a list already sorted

Tags: list, sorting, kotlin

I'm looking for a way to add an element in a list already sorted or move an existing element.

```
data class House(
    val id: Int,
    val sold: Boolean,
    val creationDate: LocalDate,
    ...
)
```

My list is already sorted on 2 parameters (sold and creationDate).

```
Example of a list already sorted :
[
    House(123, false, 2015-03-23, ...),
    House(456, false, 2015-01-11, ...),
    House(789, false, 2014-08-30, ...), // <- I'm looking for move this one
    House(147, false, 2014-02-15, ...),
    House(258, true, 2016-06-02, ...),
    House(369, true, 2015-04-20, ...),
    House(321, true, 2015-01-28, ...),
    House(654, true, 2011-11-01, ...)
]
```

Now if an house is sold, (House with id 789) how can I move an item from the first part of the list to the other part without reordering all the list. (for a performance concern)
This new position have to consider the key "creationDate".

```
List updated :
[
    House(123, false, 2015-03-23, ...),
    House(456, false, 2015-01-11, ...),
    House(147, false, 2014-02-15, ...),
    House(258, true, 2016-06-02, ...),
    House(369, true, 2015-04-20, ...),
    House(321, true, 2015-01-28, ...),
    House(789, true, 2014-08-30, ...), // <- Result expected
    House(654, true, 2011-11-01, ...)
]
```

Thank's for your help.

Comment: Are you targeting the JVM? This sounds like a use case for a `PriorityQueue` rather than a list.

Comment: I would think performance wouldn't be an issue to just sort the entire list. But yeah, would be interesting to know of a more efficient way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have:

```
val list = mutableListOf<House>(
    ...
)
val indexToMove = 2
```

You can remove the element first, then use a binary search to find where it should be inserted. `binarySearch` would return (-insertion point - 1) if the element is not found. And if the same element happens to be in the list, we'll just use the index of that element as the insertion point.

```
val removed = list.removeAt(indexToMove)
removed.sold = true // shouldn't "sold" be a var if a house can be sold?

// this should be the same comparator you used for sorting the list
val comparator: Comparator<House> = 
    compareBy(House::sold)
    .thenByDescending(House::creationDate)
val searchResult = list.binarySearch(removed, comparator)
val insertionPoint =
    if (searchResult < 0) {
        -(searchResult + 1)
    } else {
        searchResult
    }
list.add(insertionPoint, removed)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm and it divided by 4 to 5 the time of job compare to my previous way who was to sort again the entire list. (Sometimes near to 10)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the assumption that your list is already sorted, you can remove the house from the list, and re-insert it in the right place. The sold house has to be inserted at the index of the first house that has to come **after** the house you want to insert.

In this case, you're looking for the first house that is sold and has a creation date that is earlier than the house you just sold:

```kotlin
val index = houseList.indexOfFirst { 
    it.sold && it.creationDate < soldHouse.creationDate 
}
```

With removing the house from the list and converting it to a sold house, this gives

```kotlin
val houseList = mutableListOf(
    House(123, false, LocalDate.of(2015, 3, 23)),
    House(456, false, LocalDate.of(2015, 1, 11)),
    House(789, false, LocalDate.of(2014, 8, 30)),
    House(147, false, LocalDate.of(2014, 2, 15)),
    House(258, true, LocalDate.of(2016, 6, 2)),
    House(369, true, LocalDate.of(2015, 4, 20)),
    House(321, true, LocalDate.of(2015, 1, 28)),
    House(654, true, LocalDate.of(2011, 11, 1))
)

println("old house list:")
println(houseList.joinToString(", ") {it.id.toString()})

val houseToSell = houseList.firstOrNull { it.id == 789 } ?: return
houseList.remove(houseToSell)
val soldHouse = houseToSell.copy(sold = true)

val index = houseList.indexOfFirst { it.sold && it.creationDate < soldHouse.creationDate }
if (index == -1) houseList.add(0, soldHouse)
else houseList.add(index, soldHouse)

println("new house list:")
println(houseList.joinToString(", ") {it.id.toString()})
```

which prints

```
old house list:
123, 456, 789, 147, 258, 369, 321, 654
new house list:
123, 456, 147, 258, 369, 321, 789, 654
```

Comment: That's a good way. Better than reordering the list. But be carefull in your proposition `indexOfFirst` can return -1.

Comment: @Ben Right, good catch. I've updated the answer.